# Use the same google v2 reCAPTCHA siteKey for Android, iOS and web?

Tags: android, ios, web, recaptcha, captcha

We are developing an application that requires v2 reCAPTCHA.

We would ideally like to use the same `siteKey` for Android, iOS, and Web.

When the `siteKey` used for web is used for Android it says the token is invalid. The only option that seems to work on Android is selecting reCAPTCHA Android and making a new key. Android is using the SafetyNet API as recommended by google.

Do we need different site keys for Android, iOS, and web? With each `siteKey` comes to a new `secretKey`.

We would like to have one `secretKey` on the backend used to validate everything.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key we need different keys because we need PACKAGE_NAMES for android, BUNDLE_IDS for iOS, and DOMAINS for web.